# Can the free copy of windows 10 be used on another computer?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

I have an old laptop that has windows 7 and is eligible for the free upgrade. I was wondering if there was a way to get that free download as an ISO and use it on another machine instead. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, if there is an activated Windows 7 or 8 installed you can upgrade for free regardless of which PC downloaded the installer package. MrStatic is incorrect. [W10 Media creation tool here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

Answer (score 1):

The free upgrade is tied to the serial that came with the laptop. So legally speaking, no you can not do this. Please see the quoted text below.

> Windows 10 Upgrade Offer is valid for qualified Windows 7 and Windows
>   8.1 devices, including devices you already own. Some hardware/software requirements apply and feature availability may vary by device and
>   market. The availability of Windows 10 upgrade for Windows Phone 8.1
>   devices may vary by OEM, mobile operator or carrier. Devices must be
>   connected to the internet and have Windows Update enabled. Windows 7
>   SP1 and Windows 8.1 Update required. Some editions are excluded:
>   Windows 7 Enterprise, Windows 8/8.1 Enterprise, and Windows RT/RT 8.1.
>   Active Software Assurance customers in volume licensing have the
>   benefit to upgrade to Windows 10 enterprise offerings outside of this
>   offer. To check for compatibility and other important installation
>   information, visit your device manufacturer’s website and the Windows
>   10 Specifications page. Windows 10 is automatically updated.
>   Additional requirements may apply over time for updates.

From [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-upgrade)

Comment: Still unclear though for Germany, as here software licenses cannot be bound to the hw. We can even reuse OEM licenses.

Comment: If your original license was a retail license then the upgrade license is a retail license.  If it was a OEM license then the upgrade is an OEM license.  You have the same rights either way.  The free upgrade is a little different, that requires an activated copy of Windows, and only lasts until July 29 2016.  The quoted text doesn't even conform what you said....which is wrong....check the EULA